# jQuery text from span to title

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm a jQuery newbie.
I've something like the following HTML:

```
<div class=dcsns-youtube>
    <span class="section-thumb">
        <a href="some-link"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/m4-1FZeoBtQ/default.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </span>
    <span class="section-title">
        <a href="some-link">Text on the link</a>
    </span>
<div>
```

I want to get the text that is inside the a element inside the span with the class "section-title", on the example "Text on the link" an use it as a title on the a element inside the span with the class "section-thumb".

The following jQuery code only works for one single div:

```
jQuery('.dcsns-youtube .section-thumb a').attr('title', $('.dcsns-youtube .section-title').text());
```

How can I make this work if I have several divs, adding to each a element inside span with the class "section-thumb" the respective on the text from the a element inside the span with the class "section-title"?

Comment: Your final question is not clear. There are no divs in your example HTML.

Comment: @crush What do you mean. There are div in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

```
$('.dcsns-youtube').each(function(){
  $('.section-thumb a', this).attr('title', $('.section-title', this).text());
});
```

`$(someselector, this)` searches for elements inside `this`.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/umqKd/)

You might also pass a callback to `attr` :

```
$('.dcsns-youtube .section-thumb a').attr('title', function(){
      return $(this).closest('.dcsns-youtube').find('.section-title a').text();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/NRvyR/)

Comment: There are no DIV elements in the example HTML!?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to access all the elements given be selector. each() iterates through collection returned by selector and `$(this)` in the each body gives jQuery object of html `element` in the collection.

```
jQuery('.dcsns-youtube .section-thumb a').each(function(){        
     $(this).attr('title', $(this).closest('.section-title').text());    
});
```

Answer (score -3):

> I want to get the text that is inside the a element inside the span with the class "section-title", on the example "Text on the link" an use it as a title on the a element inside the span with the class "section-thumb".

That is accomplished with this jQuery:

```
var text = $('span.section-title a').text();

$('span.section-thumb').attr('title', text);
```